# GribBaglayout not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to get my Label and combobox closer together, and place my textarea in at the bottom of my frame. My combobox and label are right next to each other, but at the wrong distance, and I cant see my text area. Then when I resize the frame, everything shows up, and my combobox and textarea are the appropriate size, just at the wrong spacing. I think it is a weight issue, but when I adjust the weight number, I get no change. Thanks for the help!

Here is the code:

```
 //add menu items 
     menu1.add(save);
     menu1.add(close);
     menu.add(menu1);
     menu.add(menu2);
     //Creates tabbed items
     tab.addTab("Scan", null, tab1, "Start a scan!");
     tab.addTab("Timed Scan", null, tab2, "Start a timed Scan");

     //add GUI items 
     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     panel.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     panel.add(tab);


      JButton IPscan = new JButton("IP");
     JTextArea response = new JTextArea();
     Dimension textSize = new Dimension(400,100);
     Dimension comboSize = new Dimension(100,25);
     response.setPreferredSize(textSize);

     //Tab1
     GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
     GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    // c.weightx = .1;
     c.weighty = .5;
    tab1.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
     response.setLineWrap(true);
     response.setWrapStyleWord(true);
     response.setText("Scan results:");
     c.gridx = 0;
     c.gridy = 4;
     tab1.add(response, c);
     c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
     c.gridx = 0;
     c.gridy = 0;
     tab1.add(choseScan, c);
     scanOp.setPreferredSize(comboSize);
     c.gridx = 1;
     tab1.add(scanOp,c);


     //tab2
     tab2.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
     c.gridx = 1;
     c.gridy = 1;
     tab2.add(scan1, c);



     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Dimension d = new Dimension(500,500);
     frame.setPreferredSize(d);
     frame.pack();
     //shows everything
     frame.setVisible(true);



     return 5;
 }
```

Comment: You are probably hurting yourself by trying to set sizes and preferred sizes. Rather let the components and the layouts do all of this work for you, else you could constrain your GUI to such a size that things won't show (which is likely your problem). Also consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code, but I see one thing right away that could be causing your initial sizing to be incorrect.

```
frame.add(panel);
```

If you try something like:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gBC.weightx = 1.0;
gBC.weighty = 1.0;

frame.add(panel, gBC);
```

You will also want to do this when adding your JTabbedPane to the JPanel.